# Run GitLabRunner as connected to 2 docker networks

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I need two network interfaces for some tests of my library.
GitLab is used as a CI/CD server.
I can use `docker network create` (twice) + `docker run -itd` + `docker connect` + `docker attach` for launching a docker container as connected to the 2 networks.
But I couldn't find out any way how to configure GitLab Runner (via .gitlab-ci.yml of somehow else) for this needs.

Any help (or just additional info) is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you not run those commands inside your job? What have you tried and what error or problem are you running into?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can't run any `docker` commands (like `docker connect network_b <container_name>`) inside my job. I'll check out again tonight and past errors here.